# htaccess rewriterule to ignore prefix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i having problem creating rules that will ignore prefix on image name:

this is the request:
http://mydomain.com/image/brakepads---sample1image.jpg

rewrite rule will ignore content before "---", web server will serve this:
http://mydomain.com/image/sample1image.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule image/(.*)---(.*)\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)   image/$2.$3 [L]
```

Comment: @user705237 marking answer as **answer** is the way to say thanks:-D